# ESP32 stops sending data over WiFi randomly

Tags: tcp, wifi, esp32

I'm currently using an ESP32 under Arduino IDE to generate and send 33 bytes of data via WiFi (TCP Packets). The ESP32 is configured as an Access Point, so I'm connecting from my PC to this AP and the data is sent when the ESP32 receives an 'b'.
The problem is that after like 2 mins, the sending stops while my code is still running (I print something on the Serial port to see that).
I checked Wireshark and I noticed that the ESP32 sends randomly a packet containing FIN flag (so I guess it stops the communication without reason). [Wireshark image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67tt1.png)

How can I solve this ?
PS: I dont know much about communication protocols.

Here's my code:

```js
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiAP.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <ESPmDNS.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define NB_CHANNELS 8

#define JSON_BUFFER_SIZE 1024
// Set these to your desired credentials.
const char *ssid = "WiFi AP";
const char *password = "abcd1234";
unsigned long long timing,n=0;

WiFiServer server(80);

byte mess[]={0xA0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,10,10,15,15,50,50,0xC0};

int sin1,sin2;
int f1=20;
int f2=20;
int Fe=250;
float Te=1.0/Fe;

size_t wifi_latency = 0;
IPAddress local_ip(192, 168, 4, 1);
IPAddress network_gateway(192, 168, 4, 1);
IPAddress subnet_mask(255, 255, 255, 0);

WebServer web_server(80);
WiFiClient tcp_client;

bool streaming_enabled = false;
uint8_t channel_setting_buffer[NB_CHANNELS] = {0};

//Some initialisation functions

void process_command()
{
    DynamicJsonDocument json_document(JSON_BUFFER_SIZE);  
    deserializeJson(json_document, web_server.arg(0));  
    JsonObject json_object = json_document.as<JsonObject>();
    String command = json_object["command"];
    String return_message = "";
    bool streaming_state = streaming_enabled;  
    streaming_enabled = false;
    if (command == "b") streaming_state = true;
    else if (command == "s") streaming_state = false;
    streaming_enabled = streaming_state;
    web_server.send(200, "text/plain", return_message);
}

void start_streaming()
{
    streaming_enabled = true;
    web_server.send(200);
}

void stop_streaming()
{
    streaming_enabled = false;
    web_server.send(200);
}

IPAddress ip_from_string(String ip_string)
{
   IPAddress ip_address(0, 0, 0, 0);
   ip_address.fromString(ip_string);
   return ip_address;
}


void set_tcp_config()
{
    streaming_enabled = false; 
    DynamicJsonDocument json_document(JSON_BUFFER_SIZE);   
    deserializeJson(json_document, web_server.arg(0));
    JsonObject json_object = json_document.as<JsonObject>();
    String tcp_client_ip = json_object["ip"];
    wifi_latency = json_object["latency"];
    uint16_t tcp_client_port = json_object["port"];    
    tcp_client.stop();    
    tcp_client.connect(ip_from_string(tcp_client_ip), tcp_client_port);
    tcp_client.setNoDelay(1);  
    //get_tcp_config();
}

void stop_tcp_connection()
{
    streaming_enabled = false;   
    tcp_client.stop();
    //get_tcp_config();
}

void gen_sinus(unsigned char *mess, int n)
{
    sin1 = (int)(10000*sin(2*PI*f1*n*Te)+10000);
    mess[1]=n;
    mess[2]=((unsigned char)(sin1>>16));
    mess[3]=((unsigned char)(sin1>>8));
    mess[4]=((unsigned char)sin1);
}

void setup() {
    
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Configuring access point...");

    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
    WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
      
    delay(250);
      
    WiFi.softAPConfig(local_ip, network_gateway, subnet_mask);
      
    delay(250);

    MDNS.begin("openbci");

    web_server.on("/command", HTTP_POST, process_command);
      
    web_server.on("/stream/start", HTTP_GET, start_streaming);
    web_server.on("/stream/stop", HTTP_GET, stop_streaming);
    
    //web_server.on("/tcp", HTTP_GET, get_tcp_config);
    web_server.on("/tcp", HTTP_POST, set_tcp_config);
    web_server.on("/tcp", HTTP_POST, stop_tcp_connection);
      
    MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);
      
    web_server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  if(streaming_enabled == true)
  {
        gen_sinus(mess,n);
        n++;
        tcp_client.write(mess,33);
        delay(10);
  }     
  if(n==1000)
  {
    Serial.println(n);
  }
  web_server.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: Hi AdelAkl, welcome to SO. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this case we can't help you without your code.

Comment: @Tarmo Hello, thanks, I added my code.